# How to access network drive directly via UNC path from powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, unc, network-drive

I have been able to access UNC paths on a different domain in powershell with:
`net use \\machine.domain.int\c$\ /user:domain\user $password`

this allowed me to directly cd into `\\machine.domain.int\c$`

However I have now created a networked drive and I'm seemingly not able to do the same.

`net use \\machine2.domain.int\Drive\ /user:domain\user $password`

Results in success but I am unable to cd into the directory. However if I map the drive with

`net use Y: \\machine2.domain.int\Drive\ /user:domain\user $password`

I can access its contents from `Y:\` but not from `\\machine2.domain.int\Drive\`

What can I do if I absolutely do not want to map the path to a drive?

**edit:** The machines in question are two separate machines that are on the same domain.

**edit2:** Same thing happens when creating a new PSDrive. Both succeed but when trying to enter the directory the second one errors with: `Cannot find path 'path' because it does not exist`

**edit3:**

I did a  lot more digging and tried all the combinations I could think of

**Works:**

`net use Y: \\machine2.domain.int\Drive /user:domain\user $password`

`net use \\machine2.domain.int\c$\Path /user:domain\user $password`

`New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\machine2.domain.int\c$\Path"`

**Doesn't work:**

`net use \\machine2.domain.int\Drive /user:domain\user $password`

`net use \\machine2.domain.int\Drive\ /user:domain\user $password`

`New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\machine2.domain.int\Drive"`

`New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\machine2.domain.int\Drive" -Persist` (New error! `new-psdrive : To use the Persist switch parameter, the drive name must be supported by the operating system (for example, drive letters A-Z).`)

**Problems:**

I can not use `\\machine2.domain.int\c$\Path` because it requires an administrative account.

I absolutely do not want to make a permanent drive

It looks like one of the systems does not support using the `\\machine2.domain.int\Builds` syntax (except with net use Y:), anyone got any clues on fixing this?

Comment: did you initiate the `net use` command from the same PS prompt?

Comment: The same one I tried cd with? Ofcourse

Comment: ``filesystem::\\machine2.domain.int\Drive\``

Comment: This may be wildly over-simplifying, but have you tried `net use` without the trailing backslash on the path?   e.g. `net use * \\machine2.domain.int\Drive`?   After that, I'd review the output of `net use`, `get-smbconnection`, and `get-smbmapping` to see if you've previously mapped anything that might be interfering.

Comment: I have, also the output of `net use` is the same for both cases. I also tried this using machine2 through the filesystem path eg. c$\path and it did work in that case.

Comment: @PetSerAl with that path I get `The network name cannot be found`